# When tap on Text filed activity reload and gives warning

Tags: android, flutter, dart, crash

So I have implemented text field in my app but when I tap on that console shows this warning and close activity.

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14031): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14031): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14031): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14031): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14031): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14031): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14031): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14031): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(14031): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

I searched all over and applied suggested changes but still app is crashing. here is my code

```
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
  autofocus: false,
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
  onChanged: (value) {
    _controller.text = value;
  },
  onEditingComplete: null,
  onSubmitted: null,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80),
    ),
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.grey.shade50.withOpacity(0.8),
    hintText: "Search",
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.close_rounded,
        size: 30,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        _controller.text.isEmpty
            ? print("Nothing is edited")
            : _controller.clear();
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 onChanged: (value) {
    _controller.text = value;
  },
```

This is redundant, remove it and see if it solves the warning.

Comment: I found that on some post and  I tried that but not working. After removing it still not working

Comment: @Jaimin I copied the code you provided and faced no issue, what are you wrapping this `Textfield` with?

Comment: I wrap it with expanded widget which is in row. When I run this app on web browser app is not crashing but on physical device it keep crashing

Comment: @Jaimin Check [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9471)

Comment: I already check it